# GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading

Tags: groovy

I am working on a large code base that was written 90% in Java and 10% in Groovy. I only started learning Groovy recently and would like some advice. I have come across code like this in a Groovy method:

```
throw new RuntimeException(getErrorMessage(state));
```

This works most of the time. The problem is that on this very rare occasion, `getErrorMessage(state)` returned null instead of a String. I cannot change the implementation of `getErrorMessage()`.

I can fix this particular issue like this:

```
throw new RuntimeException((String) getErrorMessage(state));
```

or like this:

```
throw new RuntimeException(getErrorMessage(state) ?: '(no detail available)');
```

This issue would not arise if I used `@CompileStatic`, but there are other parts of the code that rely on dynamic features.

My problem is that I can only fix such issues by coming across them as a result of a bug report, which is not good for the application's reliability and reputation. (Also the problem is not just with `getErrorMessage` but with all possible situations in which an ambiguous overload exception can happen at runtime.)

How can I foresee such issues beforehand? (Currently available static analysis tools don't seem to be clever enough to catch this.)

Answer (score 1):

Do a search for all `getErrorMessage()` and replace them for `myGetErrorMessage()`:

```
public String myGetErrorMessage(int state) {
    return getErrorMessage(state) ?: '(no detail available)';
}
```

[Aspect-Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) may be overkill for this particular case, but it will get you what you want. You will still need to somehow identify all the methods that need intervention. [This](https://dzone.com/articles/practical-introduction-code) is an article describing several AOP libraries.

Comment: Thanks, but my issue is not just with `getErrorMessage`. This method is just one of countless methods that can sometimes return null. I am looking for a way to find all occurrences of code that might possibly result in an ambiguous method call.

Comment: If the problem is that Groovy decides at runtime which overloaded method to use, you can 'catch' any `null` by adding an overloaded method taking an Object. Groovy will invoke that method when the argument is `null`.